# How to curve fit scattered data with mutiple curve pattern

Tags: curve-fitting

I've encountered a problem dealing with curve fitting.
I have a scattered dataset which is plotted in the graph. From the graph, it's easy to tell there are at least two curves.
How can I fit these two curves? Or in another way, what can I do to separate the dataset to get two different data set to do curve fit?

[image]

Comment: How did you draw two smoothing lines?

Comment: Do you have additional data on the points forming the curves, perhaps that points forming one curve come from the control group while points from the other curve come from the test group?

Comment: @kevin012 I am considering using  polynomial fitting if I can separate the dataset into two

Comment: @Dave thanks. Actually the data come from the same sample. Is there any way to split the sample using some algorithm？